# Extract template arguments in Python from MediaWiki's API wikitext

Tags: python, xml, json, mediawiki

Is there a way to extract parts of text from MediaWikia's API? For example, this link dumps all the content into XML format:

```
http://marvel.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=All-New%20X-Men%20Vol%201%201&rvprop=content&format=xml
```

But there isn't much structure to it, even in the json format.

I'd like to get the text of `Writer1_1`, `Penciler1_1`, etc. Perhaps I'm not making my parameters right, so maybe there are other options I could output.

You can see the content in a more user-readable way [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=All-New%20X-Men%20Vol%201%201&rvprop=content).

Comment: Isn't splitting by `|` the content of the `<rev>` tag enough?

Comment: You can almost parse every data by using `.split(sep)` and list splicing and comprehension.

Comment: I was also thinking about using the `.split()` method too, but I am also wondering if there are other ways.

Comment: A combination of '.split()' and some regex at the line start should do the trick to extract the lines you want here, no?

Comment: This is the typical purpose of https://mwparserfromhell.readthedocs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the regex and final splitting could be more efficient, but this gets the job done for what you asked.

```
import urllib2
import re
data = urllib2.urlopen('http://marvel.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=All-New%20X-Men%20Vol%201%201&rvprop=content')
regex = re.compile('(Writer1_1|Penciler1_1)')
for line in data.read().split('|'):
    if regex.search(line):
        #assume everything after = is the full name
        print ' '.join(line.split()[2:])
```